# Read per thread network statistics from C/C++

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proc, thread, statistics

I have a Linux process with let's say 10 threads. Some of them make network traffic. From another thread or it can be even within another process I need to find out which threads have network activity. Therefore I need a way to read, either through a syscall or file system, i.e /proc this information. I'm interested in any type of network traffic that can tell me if a particular thread within that process has any type of network activity.

So I've tried to parse /proc/pid/task/net/* files, however, I always seem to get the same information regardless of which thread I query. I don't understand why...? I did the same for File IO, but that's much easier as /proc/pid/task/io provides a good summary. Important to me is to find per-thread not per-process network activity. (socket info, tcp, udp, icmp, etc).

Thanks.